# How to track who added sudo privilege to a user

Tags: rhel, security, sudo

I have a LDAP user named "ciadmin" created on the Red Hat based system without sudo privlidges. Somehow this user now has sudo privileges and can basically become root on the system.

I want to track how did that happen and who did it ?

I noticed in visudo user ciadmin is present as below. Looks like someone tampered the file but not sure who yet

```
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
ciadmin ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: `ciadmin` should be added to group `sudo`. login as `ciadmin` (by `su ciadmin`) and post output of `groups`

Comment: You can also check for group membership using `id -a ciadmin` and `getent group|grep ciadmin`. Perhaps a group called `sudo`, `wheel`, `admin` or something like it matches.

Comment: Check the last modification date of the `/etc/sudoers` file and compare the timestamp with the output of `last`.

Comment: And, the group check is still valid. User `ciadmin` might had `sudo` permissions to be used with a password and added him/herself to the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: And you might try `egrep "visudo|sudoers" /home/*/.*` to search for the `visudo` and `sudoers` in shell history files on the host.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions so far, /etc/sudoers was last updated months ago back in Jul 24 2015  -r--r----- 1 root root 7757 Jul 24 11:56 /etc/sudoers

Comment: It's possible that a package updated /etc/sudoers during installation; use something like: `rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME} %{INSTALLTIME:date}\n'` to see what packages were installed around that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can find relevant history at `/var/log/auth.log` old files are stored as compressed in `.gz` . It Contains system authorization information, including user logins and authentication mechanism that were used.

You can find out file as follows:

```
$ ls /var/log | grep -i auth
auth.log
auth.log.1
auth.log.2.gz
auth.log.3.gz
auth.log.4.gz
```

Example: I've just created user `xyz` and then added to group `sudo` and the relevant history can be found by:

```
$ cat /var/log/auth.log | grep -i xyz
Dec 18 18:54:51 pandya-desktop sudo:   pandya : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/pandya ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/useradd xyz
Dec 18 18:54:51 pandya-desktop useradd[7763]: new group: name=xyz, GID=1002
Dec 18 18:54:51 pandya-desktop useradd[7763]: new user: name=xyz, UID=1002, GID=1002, home=/home/xyz, shell=
Dec 18 18:55:51 pandya-desktop sudo:   pandya : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/pandya ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G group xyz
Dec 18 18:55:57 pandya-desktop sudo:   pandya : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/pandya ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G sudo xyz
Dec 18 18:55:57 pandya-desktop usermod[7872]: add 'xyz' to group 'sudo'
Dec 18 18:55:57 pandya-desktop usermod[7872]: add 'xyz' to shadow group 'sudo'
```

You can see line `Dec 18 18:55:57 pandya-desktop usermod[7872]: add 'xyz' to group 'sudo'` so, It gives the history that at `Dec 18 18:55:57`, the user `xyz` is added tp group `sudo`

Comment: The auth log records `sudo` usage and authentication usage, not necessarily changes to `/etc/sudoers`.  It might help though to see if a user used `sudo visudo` for instance. It does not record if someone used `su -c visudo` for instance.